# Recyclerview row format changes after search filter

Tags: java, android, search, filter, android-recyclerview

I have a recyclerview that displays a list of contacts. To differentiate between contacts that are also users of my app (let's refer to these as app-contacts) and all other contacts (non-app-contacts), i have made the typeface of all app-contacts bold (Typeface.BOLD), and non-app-contacts normal (Typeface.NORMAL). However, when the recyclerview gets filtered while searching for a contact, and app-contacts get displayed in certain rows (let's say rows 1 and 2) with a bold typeface, then those rows remain in a bold typeface. Even when i change the search, and non-app-contacts (which should be in a normal typeface) now occupy those rows (1 and 2), it’s in a bold typeface. Essentially rows 1 and 2 now remain in a bold typeface regardless of the type of contact being displayed in them.

### Here is my recyclerview adapter. the onBindViewHolder is where i change the typeface. "is Suma Contact" boolean means the contact is an app contact.

```
public class SearchRecipientHintsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SearchRecipientHintsAdapter.ViewHolder>  {

    private Context context;
    private List<RecipientsContactItem> contactItems;
    private final int SELECT_DROPOFF_REQUEST_CODE = 77;

    public SearchRecipientHintsAdapter (Context context, List<RecipientsContactItem> contactItems) {
        this.context = context;
        this.contactItems = contactItems;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.recipients_contact_row,parent,false);
        return new ViewHolder(view, context);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull SearchRecipientHintsAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        RecipientsContactItem contactItem = contactItems.get(position);
        holder.name.setText(contactItem.getName());
        holder.phoneNumber.setText(contactItem.getPhoneNumber());

        if (contactItem.getImage() != null && !contactItem.getImage().isEmpty()) {
            try {
                Picasso.get().load(contactItem.getImage()).into(holder.image);
            } catch (Throwable ignored) { }
        } else {
            holder.image.setImageDrawable(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.user_default_img));
        }

        if (contactItem.isVerified()) {
            holder.verificationIcon.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            holder.verificationIcon.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        if (contactItem.isSumaContact()) {

            holder.name.setTypeface(holder.name.getTypeface(), Typeface.BOLD);

            switch (contactItem.getPrivacy()) {
                case "Public":
                    holder.publicIcon.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    holder.privateIcon.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    holder.allowedIcon.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    holder.inviteButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    break;
                case "Private":
                    holder.publicIcon.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    holder.privateIcon.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    holder.allowedIcon.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    holder.inviteButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    break;
                case "Allowed":
                    holder.publicIcon.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    holder.privateIcon.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    holder.allowedIcon.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    holder.inviteButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    break;
            }
        } else {
            holder.name.setTypeface(holder.name.getTypeface(), Typeface.NORMAL);
            holder.inviteButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.publicIcon.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.privateIcon.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.allowedIcon.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return contactItems.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        private TextView name;
        private TextView phoneNumber;
        private ImageView image;
        private ImageView verificationIcon;
        private Button inviteButton;
        private ImageView publicIcon;
        private ImageView privateIcon;
        private ImageView allowedIcon;

        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView, Context ctx) {
            super(itemView);
            context = ctx;
            name = itemView.findViewById(R.id.recipientsCRowNameID);
            phoneNumber = itemView.findViewById(R.id.recipientsCRowPhoneID);
            image = itemView.findViewById(R.id.recipientsCRowImageID);
            verificationIcon = itemView.findViewById(R.id.recipientsCRowVerifiedID);
            inviteButton = itemView.findViewById(R.id.recipientsCRowInviteID);
            publicIcon = itemView.findViewById(R.id.recipientsCRowPublicID);
            privateIcon = itemView.findViewById(R.id.recipientsCRowPrivateID);
            allowedIcon = itemView.findViewById(R.id.recipientsCRowAllowedID);

            itemView.setOnClickListener(v -> {
                //Get position of row
                int position = getAdapterPosition();

                RecipientsContactItem contactItem = contactItems.get(position);
                String uID = contactItem.getUID();
                String name = contactItem.getName();
                String phoneNumber = contactItem.getPhoneNumber();
                String lat = contactItem.getLat();
                String lng = contactItem.getLng();
                boolean isSumaContact = contactItem.isSumaContact();

               if (isSumaContact) {
                   if (contactItem.getPrivacy().equals("Public") || contactItem.getPrivacy().equals("Allowed")) {
                       Intent returnRecipientIntent = ((Activity) context).getIntent();
                       returnRecipientIntent.putExtra("uID", uID);
                       returnRecipientIntent.putExtra("name", name);
                       returnRecipientIntent.putExtra("phoneNumber", phoneNumber);
                       returnRecipientIntent.putExtra("lat", lat);
                       returnRecipientIntent.putExtra("lng", lng);
                       returnRecipientIntent.putExtra("isSumaContact", true);

                       ((Activity) context).setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, returnRecipientIntent);
                       ((Activity) context).finish();
                   } else {
                       Toast.makeText(context, R.string.recipients_search_disallowed_toast, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                   }
               } else {
                   Intent dropOffSearchIntent = new Intent(context, SelectDropoff.class);
                   ((Activity) context).startActivityForResult(dropOffSearchIntent, SELECT_DROPOFF_REQUEST_CODE);
               }
            });

            inviteButton.setOnClickListener(view -> {
                Intent sendInvite = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                sendInvite.putExtra("address", contactItems.get(getAdapterPosition()).getPhoneNumber());
                sendInvite.putExtra("sms_body", context.getResources().getString(R.string.recipients_invite_link));
                sendInvite.setType("vnd.android-dir/mms-sms");
                try {
                    context.startActivity(sendInvite);
                } catch (Throwable t) {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Sorry, invite not working. Please use the invite in your main menu", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public void updateWithSearchFilter (List<RecipientsContactItem> newList) {
        contactItems = new LinkedList<>();
        contactItems.addAll(newList);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

### Here is the onQueryTextChange() in setOnQueryTextListener() where i filter the search and pass the result/new list to the adapter above

```
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                
                String userInput = newText.toLowerCase();
                if (userInput.startsWith("0")) {userInput = userInput.substring(1);}


                List<RecipientsContactItem> newList = new LinkedList<>();

                for (RecipientsContactItem contactItem : sumaContacts) {
                    if (contactItem.getName().toLowerCase().contains(userInput) || contactItem.getPhoneNumber().contains(userInput)) {
                        newList.add(contactItem);
                    }
                }
                ((SearchRecipientHintsAdapter) searchRHintsAdapter).updateWithSearchFilter(newList);
                return true;
            }
```

Shot 1:
[the 2 contacts displayed are non-app contacts so their typeface is normal (not bold)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ln31Q.jpg)

Shot 2. After filtering search to display an app-contact:
[the first contact is an contact (bold typeface) and the second is a non-app contact (normal typeface - not bold)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UI0Uy.jpg)

Shot 3. After clearing search filter to display contacts in shot 1:
[both contacts are non-app contacts and should be in a normal typeface (not bold). But the first contact is displayed as bold, because an app-contact (which is bold) was briefly displayed there (in shot 2) while filtering search](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cknbS.jpg)

### NB: The problem used to be caused by scrolling too. Till i @Override the getItemViewType() method of the Adapter

Initially, anytime i scroll the recyclerview, the Bold Typeface would be wrongly applied to rows/contacts that shouldn't be bold. Till i found a solution where i had to overrider the getItemViewType() method of the recyclerview adapter like this:

```
@Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return position;
    }
```

then it was fixed (for scrolling). till i realized that the problem persisted for filtering. So that's what i'm trying to fix now

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of your example that can help to understand better ?

Comment: Where do you set `isSumaContact()` in `contactItem`?

Comment: @MokhtarAbdelhalim yes please i have added the shots. came as links, not sure how to embed the pics. will try again

Comment: @Cheticamp its set in the main activity where the object is created. and in fact, the all other attributes that apply to isSumaContact() are applied accordingly. even the bold typeface, till the recyclerview is filtered

Comment: If you check the contents of `contactItems` while binding the view holders, is it what you expect? Are you resetting things appropriately after filtering?

Comment: @Cheticamp yes please all values are correct when binding. regarding resetting after filtering, im not too clear what you mean but i get the search term from the ontextchange from the main activity, then i create a new list there with the contacts that match, and then pass the new list to this adapter with the updateWithSearchFilter() method in this adapter. which updates the list in the adapter and notifyDatasetChange(). NB i i have tried implementing the Filterable for search. same result. but my method is less code that’s why i maintain that

Comment: You swap out the list, so I was wondering if there is an error somewhere in the swap out. In the 3rd image you post, if you set a breakpoint in the binding code, are you saying that everything is OK there with the list? Especially with `contactItem.isSumaContact()`? I would set a breakpoint there to check if you haven't already. I am also wondering about the coding surrounding the `startActivityForResult` and if that is solid.

Comment: okay i will share the code for where the new list is created and passed to this adapter (ontextchange). I will also set a breakpoint and observe the values of the contactItem up to where “Shot 3” occurs. however im convinced the values are correct to that point else other features would be affected too. Cus the same condition block “if (isSumaContact)” is what displays other features like the invite button or privacy icons - and they are all correct up to “shot 3” except the typeface. As for the startActivityForResult(), the problem isn't affected by it, and isn’t called at all yet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is

```
holder.name.setTypeface(holder.name.getTypeface(), Typeface.NORMAL);
```

When rebinding a viewholder with bold in place, `holder.getTypeface()` returns the bold typeface that was there earlier. Now, `Typeface.NORMAL` has the value `0`. Here's the `setTypeface()` implementation from [cs.android.com](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:frameworks/base/core/java/android/widget/TextView.java):

```
public void setTypeface(@Nullable Typeface tf, @Typeface.Style int style) {
    if (style > 0) {
        if (tf == null) {
            tf = Typeface.defaultFromStyle(style);
        } else {
            tf = Typeface.create(tf, style);
        }

        setTypeface(tf);
        // now compute what (if any) algorithmic styling is needed
        int typefaceStyle = tf != null ? tf.getStyle() : 0;
        int need = style & ~typefaceStyle;
        mTextPaint.setFakeBoldText((need & Typeface.BOLD) != 0);
        mTextPaint.setTextSkewX((need & Typeface.ITALIC) != 0 ? -0.25f : 0);
    } else {
        mTextPaint.setFakeBoldText(false);
        mTextPaint.setTextSkewX(0);
        setTypeface(tf);
    }
}
```

Note the `if (style > 0)` part there. So, passing in `Typeface.NORMAL` will just set the typeface as-is, without doing any styling on it, so your bold style will stay bold.

To fix that, either pass in a `null` for typeface if that is appropriate for you, or reset the typeface to a default that fits your needs.

In addition, there's also a perf problem in your

```
@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return position;
}
```

This makes each row have its own specific view type. But you really only have one view type, so you don't need to override this method at all. Or if you do, you can return a constant value.

Comment: Thank you so much! passing `null` in `holder.name.setTypeface(holder.name.getTypeface(), Typeface.NORMAL);` like `holder.name.setTypeface(null, Typeface.NORMAL);` fixed it!

Regarding your comment on overriding the `getItemViewType`, the bold typeface problem didnt only happen with filtering as explained here, but also with scrolling. What fixed it for scrolling is the getItemViewType override as above (which i saw as a solution to a similar question here). i dont know much about recyclerviews and why that fix worked but i will clear it to see if ur fix works for both filtering and scrolling

Comment: confirmed - that `getItemViewType` override was no longer necessary after i applied your fix. it's perfect now. thank you!

Comment: Yes, overriding `getItemViewType()` will hide some view recycling problems by preventing `RecyclerView` from being able to fully recycle views. Fixing the recycling problems removes the need for such workarounds.